# SUM and DISTINCT of two different columns

Tags: sql-server, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have a table Employee with say the following records

```
   EmpID    Salary   Date

    10      2000     1/1/2011
    10      2000     2/1/2011
    20      2000     1/1/2011
```

I want to count the total number of employees and the total salary (based on some other parameters)

Is there a easy way to write the following SQL query in entity framework.

```
  select Sum(Salary), count(distinct(EmployeeID)) from empdb.employeesalary (where clause)
```

Have a class into which I need to select these values

```
  class EmployeeEntity
  {
       decimal TotalAmount;
       int EmployeeCount 
  }
```

I currently do two queries in EF as follows

```
  objectcontext.employeesalary.Sum(c => c.Salary);
  objectcontext.employeesalary.Select(c => c.EmployeeID).Distinct().Count();
```

How can I merge these into a single statement using Entity Framework. Am I missing something here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
objectcontext.employeesalary
   .Where(c => ...)
   .GroupBy(_ => default(string))
   .Select(g => new
   {
      Sum = g.Sum(c => c.Salary),
      Count = g.Select(c => c.EmployeeID).Distinct().Count()
   });
```

Comment: The query works just fine. However, when I look at the SQL generated using tracestring (example - ((System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery)mainQuery).ToTraceString();) it gives me a complex SQL query with multiple selects and distincts. Is that normal?

Comment: That's fairly standard for LINQ. The SQL query processor *might* be able to optimize the query to produce an efficient plan. Otherwise, you're stuck writing the SQL by hand.

Answer (score 2):

how about this ? you can merge your result of EF into your Employee Entity Class

```
   var q =  from f in objectcontext.employeesalary
             where [clause]
             group f by f.EmpID into g
             select new EmployeeEntity
             {
                 TotalAmount = g.Sum(c => c.Salary),
                 EmpmloyeeCount = g.Select(c => c.EmployeeID).Discinct().Count()
             }

    var EmployeeSummary = new List<EmployeeEntity>(q.ToList());
```